# Is it possible to use Tkinter entry as input, with a button trigger, to pass values to a Signal Generator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyvisa

So I basically want to pass different values to my `Signal Generator`, instead of having a default `Frequency/Amplitude` value on my code.

I tried the `get` method of the `Entry` widget, with no luck:

I think it should look like this :

```
inst.write(f"SOUR:POW:LEV:IMM:AMPL {ampl_input.get()}")
```

But since it returns the text as string, then I should somehow pass that string to the button.

```py
import visa
import tkinter as tk


rm = visa.ResourceManager()
print(rm.list_resources())
inst = rm.open_resource('TCPIP::192.168.100.200::INSTR')

ampl = str(-20)
freq_input = str(input())



inst.write("OUTP ON")

def freqset_smb100a():
    inst.write(f""SOUR:FREQ:CW "+ {freq_input.get()})

def amplset_smb100a():
    inst.write("SOUR:POW:LEV:IMM:AMPL " + ampl) #TheSOUR:FREQ etc are commands for the instrument.



HEIGHT = 400
WIDTH = 600

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#80c1ff', bd=5)
frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.1, anchor='n')

button = tk.Button(frame, text="Set Freq", font=40, command=freqset_smb100a)
button.place(relx=0.7, relheight=1, relwidth=0.3)

button = tk.Button(frame, text="Set Ampl", font=40, command=amplset_smb100a)
button.place(relx=0.01, relheight=1, relwidth=0.3)

button = tk.Button(frame, text="IDN", font=40, command=show_idn)
button.place(relx=0.35, relheight=1, relwidth=0.3)

entry = tk.Entry(frame, font=15)
entry.place(relx=0.35, relheight=1, relwidth=0.3)

lower_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#80c1ff', bd=10)
lower_frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.8, relwidth=0.7, relheight=0.2, anchor='n')

label = tk.Label(lower_frame)
label.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: So what do you need help with? What's wrong with `inst.write(f"SOUR:POW:LEV:IMM:AMPL {ampl_input.get()}")`?

Comment: Your `amplset_smb100a` command does not know about the `ampl_input` variable unless you make that global or change your button command to pass an additional parameter .

Comment: ok so if i make the `ampl_input` global variable, the program won't open, and if i make it local, it crashes when i call the function ( by pressing the button).

Comment: Create a `StringVar`: `input_var = StringVar()`.  Link the `StringVar` with the entry: `entry = tk.Entry(..., textvariable=input_var)`.  Then use it like `inst.write(f"SOUR:FREQ:CW {input_var.get()}")` or `inst.write(f"SOUR:POW:LEV:IMM:AMPL {input_var.get()}")`.

Comment: Ok so i was thinking the same, i just made `freq_input` and tried to pass it as you suggested, technically it should be working, i get no errors, BUT the tkinter gui is not opening. @patthoyts any ideas why it's not opening?

Comment: This makes no sense, there is nothing called `ampl_input` in your code.

Comment: @Rozakos You called `input()` which will wait for you to input something in the console.

Comment: @acw1668 You are right, my bad, that makes sense now. I tried to do it exactly but i am getting this error : NameError: name 'StringVar' is not defined.

Comment: Use `tk.StringVar()`.

Comment: I'm using either slider or spinbox for that kind of things ( in Qt, but that shouldn't make a difference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def freqset_smb100a():
    print(inst.write("SOUR:FREQ:CW 150000000"))
    inst.write(f"SOUR:POW:LEV:IMM:AMPL {ampl_input.get()}")
    print(inst.write("SOUR:POW:LEV:IMM:AMPL -25"))
    print(inst.write("OUTP ON"))
```

Maybe something like this?